# CSS "border-width" (px) property bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pixel

**Q**: Is this a bug in Firefox 35?

```
$(angSelect[0], angSelect[2]).css("border-right-width", (function() {
    var angW = $(angSelect[1]).css("border-right-width");
    var boxW = selected[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var res = boxW - parseFloat(angW);
    console.log("angW: " + angW + " boxW: " + boxW + " res: " + res);
    return (res / 2) + "px";
})());
console.log($(angSelect[0]).css("border-right-width"));
```

The console logs twice throughout the code:

*angW: 199.833px boxW: 300 res: 100.167*

*49.5px*

This obviously isn't correct. The second log should read something like 50.0835. Code is executed sequentially within a window resize event.

**Results in IE11**:

*angW: 200px boxW: 299.99993896484375 res: 99.99993896484375*

*49.99*

**[NEW] JSFiddle**:

Remember to open the result in a new tab so you can zoom in and out without JSFiddle interfering. Also, open your developer console for the results in floating point format.

http://jsfiddle.net/nbsshu77/15/

Comment: Did you test this with other browsers...??

Comment: If you produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and show results from other browsers, we might be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, and the code appears to do what I want in IE11.

Comment: Unless you want pseudo-code, reformatting, or a diagram, the jQuery is essential. Edited the post for results in IE11.

Comment: Can you please give a jsfiddle or a Plunker sample for us to test it out and see for ourselves?

Comment: Okay, I'll be back with a jsfiddle.

Comment: Use the new jsfiddle. This one actually works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're expecting to. The width value is not changing because the zooming, it would be weird to do so. When your zooming in Firefox, the same value (e.g. 100px) is just displayed bigger or smaller, depends by the scale factor, but if you query the element you'll get the same size: It's like high density display.
In fact, you can actually use [devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.devicePixelRatio) to get the scale factor.

Comment: I totally get what you're saying. I feel like this is how Firefox should act. The amount of pixels should be the same amount right? But no, if you have a look at the [new] jsfiddle I posted with the developer console open, you'll see that the computed pixel amount shifts by a few fractions of a pixel. So I coded some jQuery to help combat the extra space that the fractions create, which does exist if you look closely, and is really obvious and annoying in my application. Unfortunately, the math is right, but the values come out wrong. Not in IE11 though. So that's why I think it's a bug.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. Upon second look, it seems that I can't reproduce the problem, meaning that it's something to do with the implementation I originally posted...

Comment: Wow, turns out I was able to recreate it. Updated the jsfiddle. I'm dead serious. It's more visible now. You can clearly see a black line up the right hand side of the square when zoom you in certain amounts!